# C# Regex: matching anything between single quotes (except single quotes)

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

How do I match anything between single quotes? I need to match all `attribute = 'some value'` statements within a WHERE clause of queries. I tried:

```
= '(.+)'
```

But that doesn't work: somehow messes up all single quotes and matches.

If anyone could help me out it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Do it like this `'[^']+'`

Comment: Try `'(.+?)'`. The `?` is for avoiding the regex engine to match the `'` as well

Comment: Literal single  quotes are doubled there, right? Then try `Regex.Matches(s, @"'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)`

Comment: `WHERE clause of queries` - Ah, you've suspected a single quote in the body since you mention _except single quote_. You're probably needing to match a quote inside the body of a single quoted string. Otherwise, you'd end up matching `attr = 'this and\'` me too'. Find out how it escapes the delimiter in the body, then come back with that info. It's usually done like this though `'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
= '([^']*)'
```

Meaning you want anything/everything from = ' that isn't a single quote up to a single quote.

Python example:

```
import re

text = "attribute = 'some value'"
match = re.search("= '([^']*)'", text)
print(match.group(1))
```

To read more about that, it is called a negated character class: https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html